# Can we create visualforce page without any controller

Tags: visualforce, controller

Actaully I am new to salesforce . i want to create new visualforce page without any standard or controller in that page . this page should get only user name and user profile in single page.

Could you please help on this .

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a [global variables](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_variables_global.htm) of the Visualforce. In your case the `$User` variable:

```
<apex:page >

   User Name: {!$User.FirstName} {!$User.FirstName}

</apex:page>
```

Note that you can access only a limited number of merge fields of the User. For example you can not get a `user.SmallPhotoUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that and from your requirement you could use the global variable [$User](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_variables_global_user.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fpages_variables_global_user.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)

Answer (score 0):

Use global variable in your VF page.

http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_variables_global.htm